# Buffer size and chance of ASLR brute force

Tags: security, brute-force, aslr

How does increasing buffer size increase the chances of ASLR brute force succeeding?

This is related to a project I recently did. We had an exploit_1.c program which had a buffer/character array (originally of size 517). The buffer was set to NOPs with memset. Then we were to place shellcode and the return address into the buffer, which was then written to a file called badfile. The program took one argument which was the return address. We had a stack.c program which, in a function called bof, copied the contents of the badfile into a buffer of size 12.

I had read that one method is to put a jump at the end of the NOP sled and have it redirect to the shellcode. However, the shellcode was 24 bytes, and at maximum I only had 16 bytes before the return address. So what I did is I put the shellcode at the end of the buffer.

The 3rd task we were given is to pick return addresses such that the exploit program (modified for buffer size of course) had a higher average chance of succeeding with buffer sizes 1000, 10000, and 100000. We used a bash while loop with a counter to count how many tries the ASLR brute force took.

So what I was thinking is that with more memory obviously the NOP sled will be longer. But there's got to be something more than that.

The addresses I picked were:
0xbf87f030
0xbf82e3d0
0xbfe0fb60